# Reuse persistent dblink connection

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, database-connection, plpgsql

We have a function that is quite often triggered and make a query to a remote db. If I am not wrong the connection persist just in the scope of the current call/session of the function. Is it possible to make a global connection to a remote db and reuse this connection on each function call?

Performance issue we are facing is that for transfering just 3 records a query takes more than 1s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [doc for `dblink_connect`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/contrib-dblink-connect.html) says:

> The connection will persist until closed or until the database session
>   is ended.

So it's designed to be reused across function calls.  Just reuse it.